# disable system alert boxes in android

Tags: android, sms, messaging

In the Android application that I'm developing there is a function that sends sms messages to given numbers automatically when the application is running. That function is working properly but after the messages is sent the cost for that messages prompts on a alert box. Normally when I send a message that alert box prompts. But in my application I want to disable it because it disturbs to my application. How can I achieve that.

Comment: Post the function that sends sms messages to given numbers automatically.

Comment: @ANJ Plz give your source code it will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 3):

> But in my application I want to disable it because it disturbs to my application. How can I achieve that.

What you are describing is something unique to your device (or possibly device + carrier). They modified the SMS subsystem (or the SMS client -- I am not sure whether you are using `SmsManager` or not) to display this dialog. No device that I have ever used has displayed such a dialog when sending an SMS.

You are welcome to contact your device manufacturer to see if there is a way to disable that dialog, though I doubt that it is possible.